# Cordova - Notify background running service

Tags: android, android-service, cordova-plugins, android-notifications

I am using cordova to build my android application. Since android kills service, i am binding service with a notification to avoid service kill.

Here is my method how i bind the service with notification

```
@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    context = this.getApplicationContext();
    notifyService();

    return START_NOT_STICKY;
}

private void notifyService() {
    String package_name = this.getApplication().getPackageName();

    Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, notificationIntent, 0);

    Bitmap icon = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),
            this.getApplication().getResources().getIdentifier("icon", "drawable-hdpi", package_name));

    Notification notification = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
            .setContentTitle("Smart Home")
            .setContentText("Smart Home running in background")
.setSmallIcon(this.getApplication().getResources().getIdentifier("icon", "drawable-hdpi", package_name))
            .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
            .setOngoing(true)
            .build();

    startForeground(notificationId, notification);
}
```

Here's the output

[image]

Notification is generated but notification title is not as i set. Also, when i click this notification, it's moving to app info activity. But i want to move to my main activity.

Does anyone faced this same issue? Or my code need any change for cordova?

Comment: do you wanna Cordova notification app as a service in background? Is that your question?

Comment: @Gandhi I am starting a service from my plugin. And i don't want Android to kill it. So i an using foreground notification. I can notify it with notification but notification generated is not as my notification

Comment: Shamed did you check out this plugin - https://github.com/Red-Folder/bgs-core/wiki/Build-your-own-Background-Service

Comment: @Gandhi this plugin just start and stop a service. My plugin also can start and stop the service. Problem is with notifications

Comment: I still dont understand your requirement. But just see if this link - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41689316/initiating-a-phonegap-plugin-after-device-restart/41979127#41979127 helps

Comment: Any update on this?

Comment: @Gandhi Figured it out. Problem was with my pending intent.

Comment: Ideally this has nothing to do with cordova framework then. I guess then it should not have been tagged under cordova

Comment: @Gandhi This was my first cordova project. I tried my previous code in an android studio project. It was working fine. So i thought it was with cordova. Now i have untagged cordova. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks for the info.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Figured it out after a long try. Problem was with my pending intent activity name. Below code worked for me

```
String package_name = this.getApplication().getPackageName();
Intent notificationIntent = context.getPackageManager().getLaunchIntentForPackage(package_name);
```

Comment: What was wrong with accepting the answer from [Naresh Kumar](http://stackoverflow.com/a/42759500/984830) which gave you this solution?

Comment: @NickCardoso Sorry for not specifying whats wrong with my pending Intent. NotificationIntent i passed to pendingIntent was incorrect. It should be Intent notificationIntent = context.getPackageManager().getLaunchIntentForPackage(package_name);

Comment: Good clarification, you should probably limit your answer jsut to the lines which changed, to make it clearer

Answer (score 3):

**when i click this notification, it's moving to app info activity. But i want to move to my main activity** to achieve this
change this line

```
PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, notificationIntent, 0);
```

to this line

```
PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, notificationIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
```

Hope it helps you